# How to open remote Bitbucket repository in VSCode?

Tags: bitbucket, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I often use [this *(cool)* extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.remotehub) that allows to remotely browse GitHub repositories. However, I now need to use an academic self-hosted BitBucket server (*`bitbucket.enst.fr:7900`*). I already use one repository, and all the clone/push/pull operations works pretty well.

However, is there any way for me to remotely explore some Bitbucket repositories, knowing their name and URL?

I already looked for such techniques/extensions in the VSCode Maketplace, Google, StackOverflow, Bitbucket's documentation, [Bitbucket Could Support website](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/)... but I didn't find anything relevant.

Maybe there is an extension for this and I didn't find it, or maybe Bitbucket doesn't offer such feature?